# I want the appearance of div when the conditions in the php file

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Hi I want to show the div (msga) when the first condition i want the appearance of div (msgb) when the second condition

my php code

```
if(isset($_POST['aa'])) {
 echo "a";
}
if (isset($_POST['bb']))) {
 echo "b";
}
```

my ajax code

```
<script>
$('#form')
.submit( function(e) {
$.ajax({
    url: 'php.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: new FormData( this ),
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(response){
        if (response == 'a') {
            $('#msga').show();
        }else if (response == 'b') {
            $('#msgb').show();
        }
    }
});
});
</script>
```

my html code

```
<div id="msga" style="display: none;">aaaaaaaaaa</div>
<div id="msgb" style="display: none;">bbbbbbbbbb</div>

<form id="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

 <input name="test" type="text" value="test"/>

 <input class="up" type="file" name="up" />

 <button class="submit">send now</button>

</form>
```

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form has no input with `name="aa"` or `name="bb"` so the response data to the ajax call is always empty.

Comment: I want to show div after sending · What is where edits any plans inside if

Answer (score 3):

First things, you have an error on your php.php

hence your code never execute as you expected.

> **Parse error**:  syntax error, unexpected ')' in
>   **.... on line 7**

this is line 7 :

```
if (isset($_POST['bb']))) { You have an extra ")"
```

and the space between the `if (` will give u errors.

and also

```
$_POST['aa'] and $_POST['bb']
```

does not exist.

And when you click the submit button your page will load a little trying to submit the form by the default form action, because you did not prevent it with `e.preventDefault();`

This how your code should be

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="msga" style="display: none;">aaaaaaaaaa</div>
<div id="msgb" style="display: none;">bbbbbbbbbb</div>

<form id="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

 <input name="test" type="text" value="test"/>

 <input class="up" type="file" name="up" />

 <button class="submit">send now</button>

</form>


<script>
    $('document').ready(function(){

        $('#form').submit( function(e) {

            // e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'php.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: new FormData( this ),
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(response){
                        // console.log(response);
                    if (response == 'a') {
                        // $('#msga').show();
                        $("#msga").css("display", "block");
                    }else if (response == 'b') {
                        $('#msgb').css("display", "block");
                    }
                }
            });
            });

    });

</script>
```

Then php.php

```
<?php


if(isset($_POST['test'])) {
 echo "a";
}


if(isset($_POST['up'])) {
 echo "b";
}
?>
```